# R: convolve response with probability density function

Tags: r, time-series, convolution, beta, weibull

My goal is to convolve a 0/1 response with a probability density function. I'm very unfamiliar with this kind of computation so please bear with me.

I am dealing with data for which I have 0/1 responses over time. Here is a simulation of my data and how it looks when plotted over time:

```
Response <- rbinom(10000, 1, 0.005)
Time = 1:10000

example_df = data.frame(Response, Time)

ggplot(example_df, aes(x = Time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Response))
```

[Response plotted over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpozz.jpg)

I'm trying to generate a smoother distribution of this response over time by convolving the response vector with a probability density function, such as a Weibull or Beta distribution.

However, I'm not sure what the best approach to do this is in R. What I'd like to do is something like:

```
convolve(example_df$Response, weibull_distribution, type = 'open')
```

But I'm not sure how to generate the weibull density function and whether this is the right approach.

Any advice would be really helpful!

Comment: To the Response add an error: Response <- Response + abs(rnorm(10000,0,0.01))
and use geom_point: geom_point(aes(y = Response))

Comment: Hi @papgeo! Thanks for the response, but I'm not sure how this solves my problem. It looks like it introduces some noise in the data but it doesn't convolve it or generate a smoother distribution, which is my goal.

Comment: Hi @user10123748! By "convolve", do you mean that you don't want the binomial probability of success to be fixed at 0.005 but instead to come from the Beta distribution? If so, perhaps this can help: Response <- rbinom(10000, 1, rbeta(10000,0.005,0.995)), where the parameters of the Beta are chosen to give average success prob. equal to 0.005.

Comment: Hi @papgeo, thanks for clarifying! That's not what I meant, sorry if it was unclear. I used rbinom() to generate some example data that looks like the data I have, but what I'm trying to do will be applied to already existing data (the presence/absence of a response over time). So I'm not trying to generate data following a Beta distribution. By convolution I mean that I want to replace every instance of my response (every 1) with something like a Beta density function, so that the signal over time looks more like a smooth distribution rather than a series of peaks.